# The pipe 'filter' could not be found Angular search

Tags: html, angular, module, pipe, ngfor

i am trying to use searchpipeModule but i have Filter not found error

Module:

```
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
MainVccComponent,
 ],
imports: [ Ng2SearchPipeModule ],
})
export class MainVccModule { }
```

HTML:

```
<input  name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off"
placeholder="&#61442; " class="search" kendoTextBox style="width: 280px; margin-left: 50px;"/>


<table *ngFor="let element of issuesReport | filter:searchText"
      mat-table [dataSource]="issuesReport" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Thank you

Comment: please share a stackblitz for your code.